# Locating element by classname with double underscore

Tags: python, selenium

I try to find an element by class name. Unfortunately the class name I have to select contains double underscores with raises a "no such element" error.

`div-element` to select:

```
<div class="result-list-entry__data">
...
</div>
```

selection:

```py
last_named_class = result.find_element_by_class_name('result-list-entry__data')
```

Current result(error):

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
>   selector","selector":".result-list-entry__data"}   (Session info:
>   chrome=77.0.3865.90)

Is it possible to escape the double underscores?

Comment: I am not able to recreate your problem with the information you gave.  Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi, It is great that there is code and the error message but please note that questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Comment: I can guarantee that the double underscores are not the problem. Either the element hasn't loaded yet, or it's in an iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the approach suggested before with two contains:

```
last_named_class = result.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'result-list') and contains(@class, 'data')]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use a contains query in your selector. Try something like this:

```
last_named_class = result.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'result-list')]")
```

Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check if there is any iframes. if the element is in iframe , you will have to switch to the frame, before doing anything with that element.

You can locate this element using partial string match on class attribute, something like this,

```
last_named_class = result.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'result-list-entry')]")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to get the list of all elements with class = "result-list-entry__data" by using

If you have more than one class in the DOM iterate the elementResult array  based on the position

```
 elementResult=[];
 elementResult = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("result-list-entry__data");
```

else

```
elementResult = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("result-list-entry__data");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below things,

1. Apply required wait (implicit or explicit wait)

```py
    driver.implicitly_wait(15)
```

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class,'result-list-entry')]")))
```

2. Check whether element is a child of iframe element. if so, switch to iframe and  try to click
3. Use xpath with contains if the element property value changing frequently

```py
    last_named_class = result.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'result-list-entry')]")
```